# foursquare: getting location/checkin out of a badge

Tags: api, foursquare, badge

I have a list of badge messages exported by users through twitter:

i.e. https://foursquare.com/ruben_es/badge/4f07d1fee4b026656d9dad16?ref=tw

I can't seam to understand if it's possible to access the checkin/venue connected with this badge. The web page for the badge doesn't report anything and also the API doesn't mention anything as far as I can tell.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/badge has a field "unlocks that says:
"Optional If present, an array of unlock data. Array contains checkins, which is an array of checkins. Currently both arrays will only contain 1 element.". What are these unlock checkins?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing the badges for the acting user or the acting user's friends, the unlocks array will contain a single checkin object. That check-in is the one that caused the user to unlock the badge.

So if you're looking for the location where that badge was unlocked, look at the venue object contained in the unlock check-in.

Comment: Ok, that is if I access the badges of a particular user. What if I have a particular badge, like in the question description? What would be the right API URL call?

Comment: You can not access the check-in / venue information for a random user/badge. Only for an acting user and their friends